# Best practice to pass state and state modifier to a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to refactor a component that receives a lot of properties. I am trying to think on how to improve for example with patterns such as these https://javascript.plainenglish.io/5-advanced-react-patterns-a6b7624267a6

But how would you simplify the properties in a code like this one

```
const App = () => {
    const [ab, setAb] = useState();
    const [c, setC] = useState();
    const [d, setD] = useState();

    // stuff with all available state
    return (<Example ab={ab} setAb={setAb} c={c} setC={setC} d={d} setD={setD} />)
} 


const Example = ({ab, setAb}) => {
   const [a, setA] = useState();

    // stuff with all available vars
   return  (
        <>
          <A ab={ab} setAb={setAb}  a={a} setA={setA}/>
          <B ab={ab} setAb={setAb}/>
          <C c={c} setC={setC} d={d} setD={setD}/>
        </>      
    )
}

const A = ({ab, setAb, a, setA}) => {
     // stuff with all available vars
    return <div>{a}</div>
}

const B = ({ab, setAb}) => {
    // stuff with setAb
   return <div>{ab}</div>
}

const C = ({c, setC, d, setD}) => {
    // stuff with all available vars
    return (<D d={d} setD={setD} />)
}

const D = ({d, setD}) => {
    // stuff with setAb
   return (<div>{d}</div>);
}
```

I would like to reduce the number of props, or group them. Is there any pattern of grouping those that go together? (state + state modifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for either Redux or Context Providers. If you find yourself passing props down multiple levels of components, you are doing something called "Prop drilling" which is an anti-pattern. Refactoring your components to use something like a Context Provider allows you to hold your state in a top-level Context Provider component and then access the state of the Provider using a useContext hook.

Or, if you are dealing with large volumes of asynchronous data, you may prefer to use a tool like Redux or Zustang which uses Reducers to handle state. Both approaches have their benefits and drawbacks with ContextProviders being the easiest to learn, however, Redux/Zustang have the best scalability and performance (only at an incredibly large scale though, React Context holds up just fine for most applications)

Learn Redux - https://redux.js.org/introduction/learning-resources

OR

Learn React Context - https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: what if I don't want to add a dependency because I want them to be easily testable, so I want all data to be pass as props for each component?

Comment: When you say adding a dependency, what do you mean exactly? Because you will be mocking your state returned by UseContext, so the test would remain quite simple.

Comment: I was looking for a solution where everything I need to use from a given component is provided through properties.

Comment: Unfortunately that's prop drilling. it actually breaks the first rule set out in the article you linked: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/5-advanced-react-patterns-a6b7624267a6

the author recommends using a Context provider in that instance. Context Providers at a component level are totally acceptable and a good coding practice if combined with memoisation. it lets you build really complex components with massively simplified state management. I would recommend using a local component Context Provider. That would still keep your tests quite simple. You'd need to mock your props anyway

Comment: I see, I also am influenced by this https://twitter.com/mjackson/status/1195431511417208834?lang=en

Comment: Yes, that's the situation you are currently explaining. You're building a complex nested component. You would benefit from using a scoped context as it means no prop drilling

Comment: After reading "Before you use context" and "Use cases for context" here https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#the-problem-with-passing-props I still feel there should be something between passing a dozen props and using context.   For example, why isn't it a common practice to pass in one prop the a given state and its state setter? instead of <Comp a={a} setA={setA} />. If const [a, setA] = storeA;  we could pass <Comp storeA={storeA}/> instead

Comment: Because it's more complicated to follow and you are getting into dangerous state management. If you're passing functions and variables as props across multiple components, save yourself some time and headache and use a scoped context. There are really no downsides to using it. I promise you

Answer (score 1):

[Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) is an excellent option that works very well even when you want to use Server components and don't want to have a wrapper component just to create the providers.